# .html() not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add html content dynamically but its not working.
I am taking html content from server.
and its showing only text.
Data will like commented String.

sorry for not to mention that I am working on cordova project.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
  pageurl=url+"usermenu.action";
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: pageurl,
  dataType: "html"
  })
  .done(function( data) {
   
   $("#maincontent").html(data);
  });
   
  
 /* data will like this 
    var menutbl="<table id='mpt'>"
    +"<tr>"
    +"<td id='createapp'>Create Your Application</td>"
    +"<td id='editapp'>Edit/Submit Saved Applications</td>"
    +"</tr>"
    +"<tr><td id='trackapp'>Track Application Status</td>"
    +"<td id='uploadapp'>Upload Documents</td>"
    +"</tr>"
    +"<tr><td id='viewquery'>View Queries</td>"
    +"<td id='createtmlogin'>Team Member ID Creation</td>"
    +"</tr>"
    +"</table>";   
    
    $("#maincontent").html(menutbl);
  */
    

});
```

```html
 <div id="maincontent">

  
  </div>
```

Comment: check the view source, some data is populating or not.

Comment: Is returned data a script block? If so it's wont work with ajax

Comment: data is populating. Its showing like text.

Comment: You don' see any `table` tag in `maincontent` div?

Comment: what text is comming in `data` can you post as jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

```
success : function( data) {

            $("#maincontent").html(data);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     pageurl=url+"usermenu.action";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: pageurl,
        dataType: "html",
        success : (function( data) {
            $("#maincontent").html(data);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

checkout the version of Jquery you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys to bother you problem was with server.